# OnCommand event on ImageButton control

Tags: asp.net

I have problem with OnCommand event. When I give this parametr as argument or display everything is all right, but if I used it as CommandArgument I get InvalidCastException. In code behind method CommandArgument is equal "" (string.Empty)

In my aspx file I have this code below:

```
<%# (bool)Eval("IsCandidateFavourite") %> //just display value
<asp:ImageButton id="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
    CommandArgument="<%# (bool)Eval("IsCandidateFavourite") %>"
    OnCommand="imBtnFavorite_Command"
    ImageUrl='<%# GetIsFavoriteImageUrl((bool)(Eval("IsCandidateFavourite")) ) %>'/>
```

In my code behind file I have this

```
public string GetIsCandidateFavoriteImageUrl(bool isNowFavorite)
{
    if (isNowFavorite)
    {
        return @"~/_images/icon_grid_fav.gif";
    }
    return @"~/_images/icon_grid_unfav.gif";
}

protected void imBtnFavorite_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    bool isFavorite =(bool) e.CommandArgument;
}
```

Comment: It's because data type of `e.CommandArgument` is not boolean. So, you cannot cast it by `(bool)e.CommandArgument`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Single Quotes `(')` instead Double Quotes `(")` in `CommandArgument`

```
CommandArgument='<%# (bool)Eval("IsCandidateFavourite") %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

CommandArgument is of type string as mentioned here-->    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.commandargument.aspx